# AngularJS repeat with table and rowspan

Tags: angularjs

Say I have the following data structure

```
* Key 1
    * Value 1
    * Value 2
* Key 2
    * Value 3
    * Value 4
    * Value 5
```

How, with AngularJS, can I render it in a table similar to the following:

```
|-------|---------|
| Key 1 | Value 1 |
|       |---------|
|       | Value 2 |
|-------|---------|
| Key 2 | Value 3 |
|       |---------|
|       | Value 4 |
|       |---------|
|       | Value 5 |
|-------|---------|
```

The keys are done via `rowspan`.

Comment: Josep ~ Could you please help with the below question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566520/angularjs-third-order-nested-table-structure/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Nice and tricky question!

One way to do it would be:

Given an object like this:

```
$scope.testData={
    key1:[1,2],
    key2:[3,4,5]
};
```

You could do this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, val) in testData">
        <td rowspan="{{val.length}}">{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{val[0]}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="value in val.slice(1)">
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jv0wd073/1/)

Comment: Is it easy to add an extra level? :P

Comment: @user2195592 I don't see why not, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: So each value in the example is in fact an array. I thought if I simplified it, it would be easier to explain, but I really can't work out how to add it from that example!

Comment: @user2195592 sorry, I really don't understand what you mean, if you provide me with an example of the concrete data structure that you are working with I will help you to adapt it for this example.

Comment: @user2195592 wow! But that's not the data structure that you described in your question... That's another story, let me have a look at it, please stay connected for the next few minutes.

Comment: @user2195592 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63642/discussion-between-josep-and-user2195592).

Comment: slice(1) helps not breaking your table when the rowspan is = 1, great answer

Comment: what if testData was an array itself ? and containing the same items ?

Comment: @Xsmael same thing. Just use `ng-repeat-start="val in testData"`