# AngularJS Third Order Nested Table Structure

Tags: angularjs

Say I have the following data structure

```
{
    'Key 1': {
        'Value 1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        'Value 2': ['d', 'e']
    },
    'Key 2': {
        'Value 3': ['f'],
        'Value 4': ['g', 'h']
    }
}
```

How, with AngularJS, can I render it in a table similar to the following:

```
|-------|---------|---|
| Key 1 | Value 1 | a |
|       |         |---|
|       |         | b |
|       |         |---|
|       |         | c |
|       |---------|---|
|       | Value 2 | d |
|       |         |---|
|       |         | e |
|-------|---------|---|
| Key 2 | Value 3 | f |
|       |---------|---|
|       | Value 4 | g |
|       |         |---|
|       |         | h |
|-------|---------|---|
```

The keys are done via `rowspan`.

Comment: Can you post actual data object?

Comment: Alright. See the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really, really need to do it with `rowspan`s this is a way to do it, it's beyond tricky and almost impossible to read/follow unless you are the author (sorry about that), but it works. You just need the support of a couple `$filter`s

Like this:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.testData = {
        'Key 1': {
            'Value 1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            'Value 2': ['d', 'e']
        },
        'Key 2': {
            'Value 3': ['f'],
            'Value 4': ['g', 'h']
        }
    };
})
.filter('nNestedElements', function(){
    var nNestedElements = function(collection, currentLevel, stopLevel){
        var total = 0;
        if(stopLevel==currentLevel){
            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(collection) === '[object Array]')
                total += collection.length;
            else
                total += Object.keys(collection);
        }else{
            angular.forEach(collection, function(value){
                total += nNestedElements(value, currentLevel+1, stopLevel);                
            });
        }
        return total;
    };
    return function(object, level){                
        return nNestedElements(object, 0, level);
    }
})
.filter('objectKeys', function(){
    return function(object){
        return Object.keys(object);
    };
});
```

View:

```
<table ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <tr ng-repeat-start="(key, val) in testData">
        <td rowspan="{{val|nNestedElements:1}}">{{key}}</td>
        <td rowspan="{{val[(val|objectKeys)[0]].length}}">{{(val|objectKeys)[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{ val[(val|objectKeys)[0]][0]}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="val2 in val[(val|objectKeys)[0]].slice(1)">
        <td>{{val2}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="subkey in (val|objectKeys).slice(1)">
        <td rowspan="{{val[subkey].length}}">{{subkey}}</td>
        <td>{{ val[subkey][0] }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="value3 in val[subkey].slice(1)" ng-repeat-end>        
        <td>{{ value3 }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="false" ><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eg8x5wqs/2/)

Comment: Your solution is pretty cool! Mine is more like workaround, yours actually builds all rowspans. I'm impressed! This should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 4):

It would be really cool to render this data structure with `rowspan`'s. However I'm not sure it is going to be easy to do, even using `ng-repeat-start/end` directives. Looks like much simpler to go with table and a few nested table/divs. In this case markup stays relatively simple:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td class="inner">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="(skey, svalue) in value">
                    <td>{{skey}}</td>
                    <td class="inner">
                        <div ng-repeat="val in svalue">{{val}}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4LCr4PUcZn95WUKxlUMk?p=preview

Comment: I like this solution, although I'm using Bootstrap, so it messes up the layout! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Well even if you use Bootstrap you can always style the table whatever you want. See I updated demo now it uses Bootstrap.

Comment: @dfsq +1, the way that you are doing it it's by far cleaner and easier to read than my solution... But I found a way to make it work with `rowspan`s and `ng-repeat-start/end`. Not that I would like to have that piece of code in a real app, but it was fun to find the hack, you should check it out. ;)

Answer (score 0):

YOu will have to change the data structure of the data you are having. Here I parsed the data and amid fetched the information of how much rowspan I will need in `td` during `ng-repeat` over `tr`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.item = {
    "main1": {
      "proj1": ["comp1", "comp2"],
      "proj2": ["comp3", "comp4", "comp5"]
    },
    "main2": {
      "proj3": ["comp1", "comp2"],
      "proj4": ["comp3", "comp4"],
      "proj5": ["comp1"]
    }
  };
  var parsedDs = [];
  var currRow = [];
  for(var mainKey in $scope.item){
    var main = $scope.item[mainKey];
    var mainDs = {
      val: mainKey,
      span: 0
    }
    currRow.push(mainDs);
    for(var projKey in main){
      var proj = main[projKey];
      var projDs = {
        val: projKey,
        span: 0
      }
      currRow.push(projDs);
      for(var compKey in proj){
        mainDs.span++;
        projDs.span++;
        var comp = proj[compKey];
        currRow.push({
          val: comp,
          span: 1
        });
        parsedDs.push(currRow);
        currRow = [];
      }
    }
  }
  $scope.suitableDs = parsedDs;
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='testCtrl'>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th width="100">Main</th>
      <th width="100">Project</th>
      <th width="100">Company</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in suitableDs">
      <td ng-repeat="col in row" rowspan="{{col.span}}">
        {{ col.val }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```